# File_load for image path errors when empty

Tags: theming

I need to print the URL of an image in a content type TPL file. I can do this with the following code:

```
<?php $file = file_load($node->FIELD_NAME['und'][0]['fid']); ?>
<?php print file_create_url($file->uri); ?>
```

However if the field is empty then I get errors on the screen. I tried only printing the URL if $file had a value:

```
<?php if (!empty($file)): ?>
  <?php print file_create_url($file->uri); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However im still getting the errors if the field is empty. I understand that it is the first line of the code which creates the variable that is causing the issue. How can I rewrite this to not cause errors?

By the way im a themer not a back-end developer so if there is a more 'themer friendly' solution that would be my preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here: http://www.drupalden.co.uk/rendering-drupal-7-fields-custom-node.tpl.php-templates

```
<?php
// field_my_image is the name of the image field

  // using field_get_items() you can get the field values (respecting multilingual setup)
  $field_my_image = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_my_image');

  // after you have the values, you can get the image URL (you can use foreach here)
  $my_image_url = file_create_url($field_my_image[0]['uri']);

  print $my_image_url;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your code is bugging out with `$node->FIELD_NAME['und'][0]['fid']`; the `'fid'` element (and its parent elements) don't exist so it breaks before you even get to `file_load()`.

Here's a themer friendly solution. Save yourself later headache if you just stick with render logic in your **node--TYPE.tpl.php** template. Place the `'fid'` null check in a `YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables)` inside your theme's **template.php**:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $file = isset($variables['node']->FIELD_NAME['und'][0]['fid']) ? file_load($variables['node']->FIELD_NAME['und'][0]['fid']) : null; 
  $variables['file_url'] = !isset($file->uri) ? file_create_url($file->uri) : '';
}
```

Replace YOURTHEME with the machine name of your theme and empty your cache. At that point you should have a variable `$file_url` in your  **node--TYPE.tpl.php** template that will either have the full URL or an empty string.

Comment: Should it start function YOURTHEME ?

Comment: This breaks my site. I get a white page with some of my content being shown but no styling.

Comment: No, you need to replace YOURTHEME with the machine name of your theme.

Comment: the function definition was missed. Its been fixed.

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in MYTHEME_preprocess_node() (line 179 of /home/drupalpro/websites/MYSITE/docroot/sites/all/themes/MYTHEME/template.php). =>

Comment: 179 is the line that starts $variables